# Do .NET functions follow concurrent calling?

Tags: vb.net, concurrency

I'm writing a program in vb.net and I need to have a function that doesn't follow concurrent calling and running(non concurrent function).

I don't know if vb.net functions follow concurrent calling or not! if is so, is there any options to disable concurrent calling or I should check an 'On Running' variable each time?

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you want?

Comment: @GregRos I need a function that if is called and running, if other functions call it during this process their call request pause until finishing current process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lock to prevent concurrency. in VB it is named: SyncLock.

[SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx)

In the link you can see how to protect a section of your code from being entered more than once concurrently.

Comment: As I understand SyncLock Prevents variables from concurrent updating... But It solved my problem! Thank you ;)

Comment: Please provide more information than the name of a mechanism and a link.